# Как выбрать случайную строку (несколько) из ячейки SQLite и удалить ее? (Python)

Tags: python, sqlite

У меня есть таблица, в которой хранятся товары. Вот пример товара:
[image: Пример 1]

[image: Пример 2]

Мне нужно, чтобы из столбца строки номер 1 (или любой другой, которая мне будет нужна) prods рандомно выбиралась строка (несколько), а потом удалялась (-ись).
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Чистый SQL или ORM (SQLAchemy)?

Comment: Чистый SQL. SQLAlchemy пока учу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Про работу с бд можно прочитать тут: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Потребуется реализовать два метода - получение значения "prods" из строки с заданным номером и вставка значения в поле "prods".

Предположим, что содержимое поля "prods" хранится в переменной prods в виде строки.

```
def rm_rnd(l, count): #удаляет из списка l count элементов на случайных позициях
    for _ in range(count):
        l.pop(random.randrange(0, len(l)))

    
pr_list = prods.split('\n') #разбили строку на массив продуктов
rm_rnd(pr_list, 3) #удалили из массива 3 случайных элемента
new_prods = '\n'.join(pr_list) #склеить оставшиеся продукты в строку
```

Значение new_prods нужно вставить в поле "prods" той же строки, из которой получили изначальный список продуктов.

Comment: Спасибо, попробуй интегрировать в этот код удаление нужных строк из самой таблицы.

Comment: @wender Удаление производится через замену содержимого поля - вытащили [prod1, prod2, prod3], вставили [prod1, prod3] (т.е. в результате удалили вторую строку)

Comment: Ой, я слегка ошибся - хотел написать "Попробую", а написал "Попробуй" :)
Опять-же спасибо